# Intellij, SVN plugin show lats modified date,author and revision

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, plugins

I use svn plugin in Intellij, and i have question: it is possible turn on option to show revision, author a modification date beside every file. In Eclipse it looks like in an attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have the option to show in all file lines the author of last change commited. To show this you have to right click in line numbers and select "Annotate" from the contextual menu. This isn't the same that are you requesting but maybe can be helpful.

[image]